# How to set the root path for asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, root

I have an asp.net application containing pages that lie in multiple folder. I have my .js files also in one "JS" folder and I have added their reference in head of master page like:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now when I am on home page, the script loads fine. But when I am on some other page that is present in another folder(Physics for example), the path gets appended and hence I get the error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

Similar thing is happening for my image paths and `<a>` tags also.

Now I want to give paths with respect to root path something like:

```
~/JS/VerticalMenu.js
```

But this `~` is not taking me to the root of my application. Do I need to set where `~` should lead to? And if yes then where and how??

Comment: <script  type="text/javascript" src="JS/VerticalMenu.js"></script> is how I am adding my script in head

Comment: try using a slash before `JS` like: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/VerticalMenu.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/JS/VerticalMenu.js")%>"></script>
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the Javascript file. That would probably be a separate question.

Answer (score 5):

The @Charlie Kilian answer is a workable solution however you can also specify a base URL for all the relative URLs in your page by [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) in head of your html page.

```
<head>
    <base href="http://www.yourdomain.com/anyvirtualdirectory/" />
</head>
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about the `<base>` tag. That is a good solution, too.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an ASP.NET application, you can access the root by prefixing the path `~/`:

```
<script src="~/common/scripts/safeguard.common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can also try prefixing the path with just `/`:

```
<script src="/common/scripts/safeguard.common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: That doesn't work if the application is in a virtual folder, like `http://www.mysite.com/MyApp/`.

Comment: I believe `~/` should resolve to the root of the application, even if it's in a virtual directory.

Comment: No. ~/ is not working. The path gets appended something like:http://localhost:50089/Tutorial_Pages/Physics/~/JS/VerticalMenu.js

Comment: Is this an `ASP.NET Web Site Project` or an `ASP.NET Web Application Project`? There's an important distinction.

Comment: Its an asp.net web application

Comment: Its an asp.net web application

Comment: Have you tried removing the `~` and just prefixing the path with `/`.

Comment: yes. It gives an error:Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'addEvent' is what I am getting now

Comment: So it's finding the file now, just not that method?

Comment: And now there is another problem. If I run the solution directly from visual studio, It finds the file. But if I publish and browse from IIS, it again shows 404 error.. :(

Comment: Are you publishing to a virtual directory in IIS?