# Error invoking Javascript function from .ascx file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I migrated a VS 2003 app to VS 2010.
The application has side_menu.ascx which is referenced in default.aspx.
in side_menu.ascx, a javascript function **menu** is invoked which is present in side_menu.js.

However, when the function **menu** is invoked, it gives an error during runtime - **'Cannot find function menu'** This works fine in VS 2003

This is where I am getting this error - this code is in side_menu.ascx

```
 new menu (SIDE_MENU_ITEMS, SIDE_MENU_POS, SIDE_MENU_STYLES)
```

This is the code in default.aspx

```
                    <!-- Side Menu -->
     <td valign="top" class="page_side_menu">
        <mycontrols:sidemenu id="SideMenu1" runat="server"/>
        </td>
```

This is the code in side_menu.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="side_menu.ascx.vb" Inherits="TOrders.UI.Controls.SideMenu" TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" %>
<table cellPadding="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td vAlign="top" align="left" width="100%">
        <table cellSpacing="10" cellPadding="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <asp:Literal ID="litError" Runat="server" Text="<font color=#E0E0E0 size=1>*&nbsp;</font>" Visible="False"></asp:Literal><asp:label id="lblJump" runat="server" ForeColor="#E0E0E0" Font-Size="XX-Small">Jump to Telex/Order:</asp:label>
                    <br>
                    <asp:textbox id="txtJumpTo" runat="server" Width="125px" CssClass="textbox"></asp:textbox>&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Go" runat="server" id="btnGo" class="TabOut-Button">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<script language="JavaScript" src="~/library/scripts/side_menu.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="~/library/scripts/side_menu_items.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="~/library/scripts/side_menu_tpl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
new menu (SIDE_MENU_ITEMS, SIDE_MENU_POS, SIDE_MENU_STYLES);
// -->
</script>
```

This is the javascript function side_menu.js

```
var menus = [];

function menu (item_struct, pos, styles) {
// browser check
this.item_struct = item_struct;
this.pos = pos;
this.styles = styles;
this.id = menus.length;
this.items = [];
this.children = [];

this.add_item = menu_add_item;
this.hide = menu_hide;

this.onclick = menu_onclick;
this.onmouseout = menu_onmouseout;
this.onmouseover = menu_onmouseover;
this.onmousedown = menu_onmousedown;

var i;
for (i = 0; i < this.item_struct.length; i++)
    new menu_item(i, this, this);
for (i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++)
    this.children[i].visibility(true);
menus[this.id] = this;
}
```

Comment: Rather than add another answer (as the two currently there are correct), I will mention here that the `~` at the start of a path is only recognised by ASP.NET server-side controls as meaning the base application path. It is meaningless to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

I finally found the solution to the problem. It was with the **script** tag

I rewrote it as

```
<script src="../library/scripts/side_menu.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

instead of

```
<script src="../library/scripts/side_menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing tilde (~) from javascript src path and make sure path is actually correct

Comment: I tried both of these and still getting the same error <script src="/library/scripts/side_menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script src="../library/scripts/side_menu_items.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: NOT sure if this is right - BUT do i need to add the jquery-1.1.1.js and other .js files to the scripts folder ? I dont see a scripts folder in the root

Comment: i do not see any other problems with code that you posted and no reference to jquery api but you still may have some other script errors. I would see if any other errors are reported in browser error console.

Answer (score 0):

To me it was the same and so solution is:
Change the relative path and leave them in taking away the root ~ /

**before**

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="wucDTmisc1.ascx.vb"      Inherits="wucDTmisc1" %>
<%@ Register Src="wucBeneficiarios.ascx" TagName="wucBeneficiarios" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Coolite.Ext.Web" Namespace="Coolite.Ext.Web" TagPrefix="ext" %>
<%@ Register Src="Controles/wucMoneda.ascx" TagName="wucMoneda" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<link href="~/css/content.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/css/Blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/js/siscli.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/js/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/js/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**after**

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="wucDTmisc1.ascx.vb"      Inherits="wucDTmisc1" %>
<%@ Register Src="wucBeneficiarios.ascx" TagName="wucBeneficiarios" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Coolite.Ext.Web" Namespace="Coolite.Ext.Web" TagPrefix="ext" %>
<%@ Register Src="Controles/wucMoneda.ascx" TagName="wucMoneda" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<link href="/css/content.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/css/Blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/js/siscli.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also while looking for the solution, I realized that in controls is better to leave the JS code.

It worked for me, I hope you too.

Comment: drag the JS file from the visual studio and place on the head control

Comment: I tried all the suggestions above and still getting the same error                                                                   <script src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/library/scripts/side_menu.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../library/scripts/side_menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/library/scripts/side_menu.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/library/scripts/side_menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Hi everyone, I copied the the function to the same directory as the ascx file file and changed the script tag to <script scr="side_menu.js"> and it still gives me the same error -menu not defined. Some issue with the src in the <script> tag??? I have IE 8 and Windows 7. Are you aware of any issues with this?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is maybe something as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10046033/144701). You'll have to replace the "~" with something that will follow the usercontrol where he PRESENTLY is instead of where he is landed phisicaly in the application.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/JS/VerticalMenu.js")%>"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/library/scripts/side_menu_items.js")%>"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/library/scripts/side_menu_tpl.js")%>"></script>
```

Comment: I tried all the suggestions above and still getting the same error                                                        <script src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/library/scripts/side_menu.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>                                              <script src="../library/scripts/side_menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                                          <script src="~/library/scripts/side_menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script src="/library/scripts/side_menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I believe it is a Web Application Project - how do I find out?

Comment: Here's a well explained article on MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx. Briefly, if you have a .dll for each page, you are handling an `ASP.NET Web Site Project`. Otherwise, you have a BIN directly in website's root where only one .dll is for the entire application (plus any additional dll refereced by application). It's called `ASP.net Web Application`

Comment: It is an ASp.net Web application.